# What options are available to solve an intermittent Permission Denial SecurityException?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, uri, android-securityexception

I've set up a `ContentProvider`, for my app's internal use only, to respond to a URI with a stream, through which I construct and provide a zip file.

The `Uri` is passed as an extra (`Intent.EXTRA_STREAM`) to an `Intent` (`Intent.ACTION_SEND`) in order to send it. However, when doing so, it intermittently fails with this exception:

`E/DatabaseUtils(26058): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading MyContentProvider uri content://spinner.myapp.db/file/stream/zip/1 from pid=26141, uid=10038 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()`

I've tried granting permissions through `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);`, but that hasn't worked. I also don't see why I should need to grant permissions, as it's only my own app that's accessing the `ContentProvider`.

UPDATE:

I've now also tried using `setClipData()`, with no more success. Gmail apparently ignores the Uri, and Dropbox crashes.

```
String[] mimeTypes = { "application/x-compressed" };
ClipData clip = new ClipData("zip data", mimeTypes, new ClipData.Item(uri));
intent.setClipData(clip);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Comment: Is this something you can reproduce, or that you at least see in testing? Or are you getting these exceptions from a production app? If the latter, it may be that some script kiddies are trying to access the content. And, if this is truly only for within your own app... why are you using a streaming `ContentProvider` in the first place?

Comment: @CommonsWare It's currently restricted to my development version of the app. I've been using a ContentProvider as it appeared to be the best-fit pattern for my app (including using Loaders and the like).

Comment: I can certainly see the `Loader` argument for database-style content, even though I don't use that particular approach. I have yet to see any value for in-app streaming via a `ContentProvider`, though. That being said, I don't see how you'd get this exception. When it comes up, is the `pid` and `uid` yours? Or are you somehow accidentally trying to pass this `Uri` to a third party app?

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't think the `pid` and `uid` are mine. Whose they are, I don't know. I'm just setting up an Intent as follows: `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 intent.setType("application/x-compressed");
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_FILE_ZIP_STREAM + "/1");` After that, I use `Intent.createChooser()` to select the app to send the file (Gmail, Dropbox, etc).

Comment: "as it's only my own app that's accessing the ContentProvider" -- 
no, it is not. You are not the author of Gmail, and if you are, then you are not the author of Dropbox. Nor are you the author of lots of other apps that would honor `ACTION_SEND` for an `application/x-compressed` MIME type. On newer versions of Android, `grantUriPermissions()` should work, but previously that only worked for the `Uri` that was the "data" of the `Intent`, not a `Uri` packaged in extras.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ah, I see, so the sending apps have to have their own permissions granted for each `Uri`, rather than it being implicitly provided by the calling app's `Intent`? How can I grant permissions for the app that ends up being chosen to perform the sending, or do I have to grant it to all possible apps?

Answer (score 0):

> Ah, I see, so the sending apps have to have their own permissions granted for each Uri, rather than it being implicitly provided by the calling app's Intent?

I am confused by your terminology, so let me try this approach:

There are four basic ways to implement a `ContentProvider`:

1. Have it be exported and not be secured by any permissions. This is dumb. Do not do this.
2. Have it be exported but be secured by permissions (e.g., `android:readPermission` and `android:writePermission` attributes). This works well, but only for apps that are specifically written to talk to your `ContentProvider`. It does not work for apps that have no *a priori* knowledge of your `ContentProvider`, like most implementers of `ACTION_SEND`-supporting activities.
3. Have it not be exported but for you to grant permissions on the `Uri` for a specific request. Typically, this is done via [activity flags like `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) added to the `Intent` used with `startActivity()`, though there are other approaches, such as calling `grantUriPermission()` yourself. This works great when you are the initiator of the need for third-party access to your provider, such as starting an activity with an `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`.
4. Have it not be exported, and not grant permissions on the `Uri`. In this case, the `ContentProvider` is only available within your own app and cannot be accessed at all by third parties, even if you ask (e.g., your `ACTION_SEND` request).

> How can I grant permissions for the app that ends up being chosen to perform the sending, or do I have to grant it to all possible apps?

This gets to a mistake in my one comment, for which I apologize.

`FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` nowadays grants read access to your `Uri` in your `Intent`, whether that `Uri` is the "data" of that `Intent` or is in an extra. This will be granted to the end consumer of the `Intent` -- in other words, the chooser does not somehow consume the permission and the chosen activity not have permission. However, it used to be that `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` only worked on the "data", not on `Uri` values in extras, and off the top of my head I forget exactly when that flaw was fixed.

`grantUriPermission()` requires you to know who the end consumer of the `Intent` will be, which means you would need to roll your own "chooser", so you can find out the actual app the user wants to handle your proposed `ACTION_SEND` request.

FWIW, [here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) that demonstrates the use of `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`, to view a PDF served by a `FileProvider`.

Comment: I'm targeting Android 4.3 (version 18) with `minSdkVersion="15"` and I think I'm running into the issue you mention, that of `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` only operating on the `Uri` set through `setData()`, rather than `putExtra()`. Unfortunately setting the `Uri` as the data rather than an extra doesn't seem to be suitable for sending a file, such as an an attachment (Gmail puts the `Uri` into the _To_ field, and Dropbox just crashes). I've looked for documentation about this change, but haven't been able to find any as yet.

Comment: I've found some mention of this changed behaviour in the [documentation for ACTION_SEND](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND), with specific reference to the use of  `setClipData()`. Haven't been able to get it to work as yet, though; Dropbox still just crashes and Gmail doesn't attach any file.

Comment: @Spinner: I'll have to write up some samples for this. The problem with `setClipData()` is that clients also need to change to use the `ClipData`, and probably many do not. In particular, if Dropbox is crashing with the same error as before, they're probably not paying attention to the `ClipData` at all and are just using the `Uri` (and failing as a result). I don't know why Gmail would not crash yet not attach the file, though, unless the whole `Uri` is invalid.

Comment: Do you have information about when precisely the change happened that caused `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to work on the extras? Since the `setClipData()` change was made in Jelly Bean, one would have thought it came in then; however, since I'm running on 4.3, this would imply that the change was only made in 4.4. That's assuming my set-up is functioning correctly.

Comment: @Spinner: `setClipData()` has been around since 4.1. That being said, I am now having difficulty finding my reference for if/when `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` works with extras. I may be misremembering.

Comment: The weird thing is that sometimes, perhaps 1 time in 10, the file will go through without raising any `SecurityException`. (This is using the original `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)` method.) The inconsistency is baffling.

Comment: Can AppA send an intent to an activity of AppB (the one with the not exported/uri granting App) and then receive back an Uri (with permission granted) inside an Intent to then query the contentResolver with this Uri ? 
Or am I misunderstanding something ?

Comment: @Lakedaemon: "Can AppA send..." -- `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` is put on an `Intent`, not a `Uri`.